# QGIS Crashes with OpenLayers plugin

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I've just updated to QGIS Brighton on Ubuntu 14.04, and I've noticed that when I open Openlayers plugin, in order to load google layers, the whole program suddenly crashes.

The only log I see, when open with terminal is this:

```
setLayerType: Google Hybrid
 setLayerType: Google Hybrid
OpenlayersController.__init__
[WORKER THREAD] Calling request() asynchronously
[WORKER THREAD] Waiting for the async request to complete
[GUI THREAD] Processing request
page file: file:////home/pablo/.qgis2/python/plugins/openlayers_plugin/weblayers/html/google_hybrid.html
OpenlayersWorker waiting for page to load
Violación de segmento (`core' generado)
```

Does anybody know something about?

Comment: Is your OpenLayers plugin also up-to-date? I had to update mine when I upgraded to QGIS 2.6 (although I use Windows).

Comment: Yes, is up-to-date. And it seems that crashes not only with Google Layer, but with any other layer in this plugin.

Comment: Could be a possible bug, hopefully others can also advise.

Comment: Use the QuickMapServices plugin instead of OpenLayers.