# Aerial Image basemap: Problem with QGIS QuickMapServices Plugin MapQuest Layer

Tags: qgis, basemap, mapquest, qgis-2.18

I need a areal image or satellite Image  as a basemap for some maps. Since I have read that the OpenLayers plugin is no longer supported [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/121821/26687), [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/172022/26687) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/172022/26687) (just to name a few), I changed to the QuickMapServices plugin.

However, now I'm trying to get a high-resolution areal / satellite image as a base map and therefore I chose the MapQuest Aerial layer. Yet, this plugin does not work. I am getting the error message

> `QuickMapServices: Failed to download all xx files. - MapQuest Aerial`

[image]

I checked the CRS. It is set to EPSG:3857 (WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator) and I also tried others.

Do you know how to solve this error? Or is there another plug-in that provides high-res basemap imagery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MapQuest  no longer provide a tile server for free:
https://developer.mapquest.com/forum/mapquest-open-tiles-being-discontinued

Thus it cannot be used in QuickMapServices anymore.

But the plugin can load in Google and Bing aerial imagery see: [Google Maps not Showing in QGIS 2.12](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175043/google-maps-not-showing-in-qgis-2-12)

Comment: Is there another provider?

Comment: See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175043/google-maps-not-showing-in-qgis-2-12 on how to add Google/Bing imagery.